# Move framed label alongside y-axis

Tags: plotting, labeling

Maybe the answer to this question is trivial but I am stuck with my last modification for hours now. In my plot i added framed labels to add a certain distance of the labels from their axes. This works well but due to the final viewpoint of the plot the y-label (U [V]) seems to be badly positioned. Also the ticks cut the axis, which should be avoided. How may i move the framed label in direction of the plot origin or even ad total positions to the label frames and reposition the ticks in -x direction? Finally it shall be positioned somewhere in between tick 30k and 50k. If possible i would like to reposition the x-label accordingly.

```
colors = {{1, RGBColor[1, 0.11, 0.02]}, {2, 
   RGBColor[1, 0.22, 0.23]}, {3, Orange}, {4, 
   RGBColor[0.93, 0.79, 0.05]}, {5, RGBColor[0.77, 0.84, 0.09]}, {6, 
   RGBColor[0.57, 0.86, 0.15]}, {7, 
   RGBColor[0.13, 0.81, 0.17]}}; ListPlot3D[{{2, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {2, 4, 
   5, 5, 4}, {2, 5, 6, 6, 5}, {3, 5, 6, 7, 6}, {3, 5, 6, 7, 6}}, 
 Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.002], 
 DataRange -> {{10000, 50000}, {10000, 90000}, {0, 10}}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[i, {i, 10000, 50000, 10000}], 
   Table[i, {i, 10000, 90000, 20000}], Table[i, {i, 0, 7, 1}]}, 
 TicksStyle -> 14, AxesOrigin -> {10000, 10000, {1, 7}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Framed["\[Omega] [rpm]", FrameStyle -> None, 
    FrameMargins -> 14], 
   Framed["U [V]", FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 17], 
   Framed[Rotate["category", 90 Degree], 
    FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 11]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive["Calibri", Bold, 18], ImageSize -> Large, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[colors, #3] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,  
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {1, 7}}, 
 ViewPoint -> {0.8 Pi, -1.7 Pi, 0.7 Pi}
 ]
```

Comment: Please strip your code to the bare minimum to show your problem.

Comment: Thanks, i tried to reduce the code to the necessary minimum.

Comment: The red coloring indicates some syntax errors - please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest manual positioning of your labels with `Epilog`:

```
ListPlot3D[
 {{2, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {2, 4, 5, 5, 4}, {2, 5, 6, 6, 5}, {3, 5, 6, 7, 6}, {3, 5, 6, 7, 6}},
 Epilog -> {Text["U [V]", {-0.1, 0.85}], Text["\[Omega] [rpm]", {0.2, 0}]},
 AxesLabel -> {None, None, Rotate["category", 90 Degree]},
 ViewPoint -> {0.8 Pi, -1.7 Pi, 0.7 Pi}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank Your very much, editing the positioning and adding the "style" option to your solution (e.g. Epilog -> {Text[Style["U [V]", FontSize -> 18, Bold], directly solved my problem.

Comment: @StephanJ Glad to help =) Could you please officially accept my answer by selecting the tick mark on the left side?